# java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to Object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my class UserModel

```
public class UserModel {

private String userName;
private String password;

public UserModel(String userName, String password) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
}
```

This is my way to get data from firebase

```
userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap<String, UserModel> userModelHashMap = (HashMap<String, UserModel>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            ArrayList<UserModel> userModelList = new ArrayList<>(userModelHashMap.values());
            if (userModelList.size() != 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + userModelList.get(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

It logs successfully.

> onDataChange: {password=abcde, userName=1234}

Everything seems to be ok until I want to log more detail

```
Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + userModelList.get(0).getUserName());
```

And here is the error of this line after I change my code

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to qklahpita.vn.testfirebasedemo.UserModel

I cannot understand why getUserName() get wrong. If **userModelList.get(0)** do not return UserModel, what does it return?

Comment: Use the debugger and you will know.

Comment: you cannot simple change using type casting use contsructor to add dynamicaly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because the data you are getting is in the form of 'HashMap' and not 'UserModel'.You can do this to create objects instead.

```
UserModel userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
```

Edit : You also need to loop through children if there are multiple users. Like this.

```
for(Datasnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapsot.getChildren(){
   UserModel userModel = userSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before and received a userModel with username & password = null. Here is my data when I call dataSnapshot.getValue() `{id1={password=1234, userName=abcd}, id2={password=5678, userName=cde}}`

Answer (score 0):

When you set a Value on Database since a Class as UserModel, only will be published those variables that you set **public**, and not **private**.

**Private**: null values
**Public** : right Values